# Python3 and cx_freeze - TypeError positional arguments

Tags: python, arguments, cx-freeze

I've generated an exe file using cx_Freeze and Python 3.2, but when I run the file, it stops at a function call with the following error:

TypeError: foo() takes exactly 4 positional arguments (5 given)

Here is my code:

```
class myClass:
   foo(self, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4):
      pass
      ....
      return
```

The function is called like:

```
myVar = mcClassObject.foo(otherClass.member, "a", "b", "c")
```

In the exclipse environment everything works fine.

Any help appreciated.

Cheers,
Uli

Comment: Is that the only place `foo` is called? It looks fine.

Comment: Check that `mcClassObject` is definitely an *instance*, not a *class*, because I think that's exactly the error you'd get if it was a class. Also, check the line number in the traceback to make sure you're looking at the right call.

Comment: @hbcdev: yes, it is the only place where foo is called

Comment: @Thomas: it is an instance, an earlier call with this instance and another memeber function of myClass with only 1 paarmeter works fine. Problem occurs only in compiled version

Comment: Hmm, actually, calling the method on the class would have the numbers the other way around. I can't see how freezing could affect it, though - is there anything in your code that might be working differently, e.g. falling back to a different code path because something else has failed?

Comment: I can't find a different code or something else that could casue a fallback. But found a strange thing some minutes ago. When I rename the function 'foo' to 'foo_new' and change the line wiht the function call to the new name, make a new compile with cx_freeze and the error now is: AttributeError: 'myClass' object has no attribute 'foo_new' - Strange :-(

Comment: Is it defined in another file? Could you be freezing an older version of the module where it is defined?

Comment: found the problem -> not my current source files of myClass were used in the compiler but some older version in the site-packages folder...bloody hell. sorry for bothering....